# Whether the User-Defined Algorithm on PAI is supported in Alibaba Cloud

Tags: alibaba-cloud

I am in the development of Machine learning/Deep learning applications in the PAI service of Alibaba Cloud, Now I have to create a user-defined Algorithm in the PAI of AlibabaCloud.I have to know whether the user-defined Algorithm is supported in Alibaba Cloud and if  supported I which all regions it is supported

Comment: And - you are not able to read this in the documentation why?

Answer (score 0):

PAI-Studio is a graphical User Interface(GUI) based distributed modelling platform with drag and drop feature. It has 200 algorithms covering data preprocessing, future engineering, model training, model evaluation, and prediction. Currently, it supports user-defined algorithm in China Region and it is yet to release this feature in the International region.